# Object not defined...dynamically loading scripts and creating objects defined in them throws error

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm loading some scripts returned from the server...some have objects defined in them...appending the scripts to the body and trying to create a new object considering the scripts and hence object definitions loaded in the page...Which is not the case as this is throwing object not found error...here's how the code looks...

```
for(var i=0; i < paths; i++){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type='text/javascript';
    script.src=paths[i].src;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
var new_obj = new object_name(a, b, c); // object_name not found
```

I can see the script have been successfully appended to the body in elements tab.

I've tried loading the script at the end of the page body manually and its working that way but not when i'm adding the file dynamically...Please tell me whats going wrong....

Comment: Have you tried delaying the `new object_name()` till after the `script.onload` event occurs?

Comment: No...didn't try that...there are several files  loaded in the for loop...how should I use the onload for this particular script?

Comment: Is there any way to use onload inside for loop delaying its execution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `async` property to `false` (to load scripts synchronously in the order) and implement `onload` event to verify whether the script is loaded. Below code shows the implementation. I may be wrong in the implementation or there could be better way for loading scripts based on array (looping) and check for all files loaded.

```
 <script>
       window.onload = function () { LoadFunctions();  }
       var paths = ["test.js", "test2.js"];

       function LoadFunctions() {
           for(var i=0; i < paths.length; i++){
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.type='text/javascript';
                script.src=paths[i];
                script.async = false;
                script.onload = function() { callFunctions(); }
                document.head.appendChild(script);
            } 
        }

        function callFunctions(){
            if (typeof test1 != "undefined") test1(); //Check for function in test.js whether loaded or not then execute it
            if (typeof test2 != "undefined") test2(); //Check for function in test2.js whether loaded or not then execute it
        } 
</script>
```

test.js

```
function test1(){
    alert("Alert from test.js");
}
```

test2.js

```
function test2(){
    alert("Alert from test2.js");
}
```